# Flutter: How to save my fontsize value with slider through sharedpref

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

Hello in my app I will control my `fontSize` with a `Slider` and control the slider with a `checkbox` so if the user wants to change the size they will enable the checkbox so

i want that if user will change the slider to change the font that will save in local storage of that device how can i do it?

code:

```
 bool toggle = false;
  int _value = 38;
Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child:
                Switcher(

                  size:SwitcherSize.small,
                  curveType: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
                  colorOn: Colors.green,
                  colorOff: Colors.redAccent,
                  iconOn: Icons.done,
                  iconOff: Icons.dangerous,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    toggle = value;
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
              flex: 12,
                child: Slider(
                  thumbColor: Colors.red.shade900,
                  value: _value.toDouble(),
                  activeColor: Colors.black,
                  inactiveColor: Colors.grey.shade400,
                  onChanged: (double s) {
                    setState(() {
                      if (toggle == false) {
                        return null;
                      }
                      if (toggle == true) {
                        _value = s.toInt();
                      }
                    });
                  },
                  min: 20.0,
                  max: 60.0,
                ),
                // switchcase(),
              ),
//call here
  fontSize: _value.toDouble(),
```

this code will properly plz tell me how i will save this in shared pref

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';


class MySliderWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MySliderWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MySliderWidget> createState() => _MySliderWidgetState();
}

class _MySliderWidgetState extends State<MySliderWidget> {
  bool toggle = false;
  double _value = 38;
  late SharedPreferences _pref;
  String prefKey = "value";

  // function to save to pref
  void saveOnPref(double value) async {
    _pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _pref.setDouble(prefKey, value);
  }

  // this function load and update value
  void loadFromPref() async {
    _pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      _value = _pref.getDouble(prefKey) ?? 38.0;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    loadFromPref();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text(
          "test",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: _value),
        ),
        Switch(
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              toggle = !toggle;
            });
          },
          value: toggle,
        ),
        Slider(
          thumbColor: Colors.red.shade900,
          value: _value,
          activeColor: Colors.black,
          inactiveColor: Colors.grey.shade400,
          min: 20.0,
          max: 60.0,
          onChanged: toggle
              ? (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _value = value;
                  });
                  saveOnPref(value);
                }
              : null,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Install [`shared_preferences`](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) and Create a separate dart class like this. ( Creating a separate dart file is not mendatory but it's recommended for clear code and preventing Spaghetti Code. )

   ```
   import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
   class SharedData{
      static Future<void> saveFont(int fontSize) async{
      // Obtain shared preferences.
      final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

      // Save an integer value to 'font_size' key.
      await prefs.setInt('font_size', fontSize);
    }
    static Future<int> getFont() async{
      // Obtain shared preferences.
      final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

     // Get an integer value from 'font_size' key.
     int? fontSize = await prefs.getInt('font_size');
     return fontSize ?? 12;
     }
   }
   ```
2. Call this method when you want to save `font_size` to `shared prefs` like this.

   ```
   Slider(
   ....
   onChanged: (double s) {
        setState(() async {
          if (toggle == false) {
            return null;
          }
          if (toggle == true) {
            _value = s.toInt();
            /// Save font size to shared prefs
            SharedData.saveFont(_value);
          }
        });
      },);
   ```
3. If you wannna load `font_size` from `shared prefs` in `initState`, use like this.

   ```
     /// Get font size from shared prefs
     SharedData.getFont().then((fontSize){
       setState((){
         _value = fontSize;
       });

     });
   ```

Feel free to give it a go.